# How to format a throw statement in Erlang?

Tags: exception, erlang

I am new to Erlang syntax and struggling with this. I can do this and compile:

```erlang
1> throw("testing 123").
** exception throw: "testing 123"
```

which is of type `throw/1`.

I want to be able to do this:

```
%% I have seen this code in sample examples.
?THROW("Couldn't start process: ~p. ~n", [Reason])
```

I do not think there is `throw/2.` Then how can I define a *macro* like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?THROW is a macro. It should be define somewhere as:

```
-define(THROW(Format,Params),throw(io_lib:format(Format,Params))).
```

In this definition, the call to `io_lib:format(Format,Params)` returns a single string that is used as Reason by the function throw.